# eksct error unmarshaling JSON during processing YAML file

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am getting error during applying YAML config to AWS K8s cluster:

Error:

```
couldn't create node group filter from command line options: 
loading config file "K8s-nodegroups/group_test.yaml": error unmarshaling JSON: 
while decoding JSON: json: unknown field "fullEc2Access"
```

Here is the command which I am using:
`eksctl create nodegroup -f K8s-nodegroups/group_test.yaml`

And here is my YAML:

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig

metadata:
  name: some-cluster-name
  region: eu-west-2

nodeGroups:
  - name: "group-test"
    instanceType: t3.small
    desiredCapacity: 1
    subnets:
      - eu-west-2a
      - eu-west-2b
    maxSize: 2
    minSize: 1
    fullEc2Access: true
    spot: true
    maxPodsPerNode: 100
    volumeSize: 8
    volumeType: gp3
    labels: { group: test }
```

And there is not error related to `fullEc2Access`, if I remove it I will get next one:

`...error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: unknown field "spot"`

Why my file is trying to precess like a JSON?
How I can fix it, I got this example form docs and checked it many times.

I know that I can use "one line" command to create nodegroup, but I want to use YAML.
How it is possible to fix it?

I tried eksctl `0.131.0` and `0.128.0` versions - same errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**fullEc2Access** does not exists as a property in the schema, **spot** is a property of *ManagedNodeGroup*, not *NodeGroup*.

See [EKS Config File Schema](https://eksctl.io/usage/schema/) for further info, or you can print the default schema using the command

```
eksctl utils schema
```